# JSON from localstorage not able to decode in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, html, local-storage

I am fetching values from localstorage as JSON and trying to decode.
But its not working.

This my code to fetch JSON from localstorage:

```
$items = "<script> document.write(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('itemList')))); </script>";
```

When i echoed above `$items` it resulted like this:

```
{"items":[{"name":"Guitar","id":"1"}]}
```

Decoding above json like this:

```
$decoded = json_decode($items, true);
```

When i am trying to echo `$decoded` not displaying anything. When i did `var_dump($decoded)` its showing `NULL`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Em... what are you going to achieve? It's a totally wrong code. String won't behave as JS... it's just a plain string. You have to separate JS and PHP part

Comment: @FieryCat - I am trying to get localStoarge json values to php and decode it using php

Comment: @FieryCat - I am able to fetch JSON from locaStorage though

Comment: `$decoded = json_decode('{"items":[{"name":"Guitar","id":"1"}]}', true);` - workable; your sample - never

Comment: @FieryCat - May i know why?

Comment: @FieryCat - How do i fetch data from localStorage then? To decode in php?

Comment: Use JavaScript to execute `JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('itemList'))` and send to PHP as post value; in PHP `$items = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'key');`

Comment: @FieryCat - Not getting it. You have any example link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is that you're not able to combine JS/PHP "in one line".

```
$items = "<script> document.write(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('itemList')))); </script>";
```

`json_decode` from `$items` will give you directly the code that you've put in (check `json_last_error()`)... without any JS execution (or you have to use PhantomJS; but it's not your case).

How it has to be:

- JS part (sample.js):

  ```
  jQuery.post('sample.php', {
      'item': JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('itemList'))
  });
  ```
- PHP part (sample.php)

  ```
  $items = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'item');
  $decoded = json_decode($items, true);
  var_dump($decoded);
  ```

Comment: Okay will try that

Comment: This code didn't meet my requirement. But this is the right code as i have checked

Answer (score 0):

localStorage only stores strings.  The JSON.stringify() is wrong since it expects a JSON object, not a string, as input.

Comment: Should i be using only JSON.parse ??

Comment: Your command looks weird.  What line writes the JSON to localstorage?

Comment: Yes, JSON.parse should give you a JSON object from the localStorage string.

Comment: Only `JSON.parse` is giving `[object object]`

Comment: You have to stringify the JSON object again if you want to print it.